# connecting a C program with python3 with pipes

Tags: c, python-3.x, pipe

Hi so i was trying to communicate to a C "server" from python through pipes and i get a UnicodeDecodeError and i don't get why, here are both codes:

"Server" in C:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_BUF 1024

int main(){
    int fd;
        char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";
    char *menu;

    // create FIFO pipe
        mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);

    while(1){


            // open the pipe for writing, and send a message to the client
            fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
            //fd = open(myfifo, O_NONBLOCK);
            //fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
        menu = "conectado a servidor con PIPE Escribe 'exit' para desconexión\n";
            write(fd, menu, 1000);
            close(fd);
        sleep(10);
        // open the pipe for reading, and print the message received from the client
        char buf[MAX_BUF];
            fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);    
            read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
        if(strcmp("exit",buf)==0){
            break;
        }else{  
            printf("Recibido: %s\n", buf);
        }           
            close(fd);
    }

    // remove the pipe
        unlink(myfifo);

        return 0;
}
```

and "Client" in python:

```
import os,sys,errno,pipes


def Prueba():
    print ("creating pipe and connecting...")
    p = pipes.Template()
    fifo = "/tmp/myfifo"
    f = p.open(fifo,'r')
    try:
        algo = f.read()
    finally:
        f.close()
    print (algo)
```

and the error that i have is:

```
algo = f.read()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 97: invalid start byte
```

any help/comment/suggestion on the code will be welcomed, thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried `p.open(fifo,'rb')` ?

Comment: yeah and it tells me Template.open must be 'r' or 'w' only

Comment: you could try without pipes. `f = open(fifo,"rb")`, since the pipe is created by the C program. Now you have binary. To hell with encoding.

Comment: it kind of worked, it prints me the C message but with a lot of trash, like: b'conectado a servidor con PIPE Escribe \'exit\' para desconexi\xc3\xb3n\n\x00exit\x00Recibido: %s\n\x00\x00\x01\x1b\x03;8\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x004\xfc\xff\xff\x84

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting garbage after your text because you're sending like this:

```
        write(fd, menu, 1000);
```

The `1000` should be `strlen(menu) + 1` to send a null-terminated string, for example.